# WebScraping - Extracting a value from td class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a simple Py web scraping file to extract specific values from a table on web page, but the results aren't coming in the current formal. I guess I'm doing something incorrect with the soup.find command.

```
URL = 'https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/news/Pages/20200329_01.aspx'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('td', class_='moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6')
print(results)
```

I'm expecting the value of 93,099, but the print provides the result

```
<td class="moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6">93,099</td>
```

I'm not able to convert the  format of results into string either.

A screenshot in case it helps
[image: A screenshot in case it helps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it using `contents` property.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/news/Pages/20200329_01.aspx'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('td', class_='moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6')
if results and results.contents :
   print(int(results.contents[0].replace(',','')))
```

In the future, whenever you do not know the properties of the object returned use `__dict__` to decode the object.

As an example,

```
>> results.__dict__
{'attrs': {'class': ['moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6']},
 'can_be_empty_element': False,
 'cdata_list_attributes': {'*': ['class', 'accesskey', 'dropzone'],
  'a': ['rel', 'rev'],
  'area': ['rel'],
  'form': ['accept-charset'],
  'icon': ['sizes'],
  'iframe': ['sandbox'],
  'link': ['rel', 'rev'],
  'object': ['archive'],
  'output': ['for'],
  'td': ['headers'],
  'th': ['headers']},
 'contents': ['93,099'],
 'hidden': False,
 'known_xml': False,
 'name': 'td',
 'namespace': None,
 'next_element': '93,099',
 'next_sibling': None,
 'parent': <tr class="moh-rteTableFooterRow-6"><td class="moh-rteTableFooterEvenCol-6">Total</td>
 <td class="moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6">93,099</td></tr>,
 'parser_class': bs4.BeautifulSoup,
 'prefix': None,
 'preserve_whitespace_tags': {'pre', 'textarea'},
 'previous_element': '\n',
 'previous_sibling': '\n',
 'sourceline': 1075,
 'sourcepos': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I used results.string to get it into a cleaner format, and then converting into int() by removing the , first.

Comment: What if corona virus case increases 100 times an one more comma is added ? Better use str.replace()

Comment: Choose your methods wisely. There is another method called results.strings that gives you all strings. Read up documentation and check if everytime use of such method makes sense.

Comment: This is what I did:
t_tests = int(soup.find('td', class_='moh-rteTableFooterOddCol-6').string.replace(",",""))

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `.text` to `results` as follows:

```
print(results.text)
```

Comment: In some cases, when there is a null value present in the table, using ```.text``` will replace the null values with blank spaces, which is not treated as ```NaN```. How to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1):

changing `print(results)` to `print(results.string)` will display in the console:

93,099
is this what you wanted?